# Peugeot 406 won't start in cold weather

Tags: engine, starting, diesel, peugeot

I drive a Peugeot 406 2.0 HDI, 2001.
This morning it was -13 °C (9 °F) and the engine couldn't start.
First two times, I could hear the engine running, but the third time it died and my temporary data was restarted (clock, date etc.).
After I came from work, temperature was -4 °C (25 °F) and it started without any problems.
I recharged the battery but it took very little time for complete charging.
The battery is older than 10 years and the car was not used for a few months (up to 6).
Is it just a battery problem or could it be something else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Battery is probably the first thing to check, but given that it's a Diesel with cold start problems I would also get the glow plugs checked or check them yourself if it still has them.

Comment: You were right. 3 out of 4 glow plugs were gone.